# Autopopulate Tuesdays, Thursdays, Saturdays starting from a fixed date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to auto-populate dates from a fixed date in Google Sheets.
Essentially, I want it to auto-populate the dates for every Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday.

I have found stuff on skipping weekends, but nothing like this and I am stumped - which is not hard to do!

Answer (score 4):

In the enumeration used by [`weekday`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) function by default, Tuesdays, Thursdays and Saturdays are days 3, 5, and 7 of the week. The solution I give below is not special to these particular days: you can replace `{3,5,7}` below with any other selection of days of week.

```
=A2 + 1 + min(arrayformula(mod({3,5,7} - weekday(A2) - 1, 7)))
```

This is a formula that would appear in A3, computing the next date based on A2. The starting date at A2 doesn't have to be in the acceptable range itself.

Explanation:

- `A2 + 1` is *tomorrow*, the minimal possible value of A3. We want to find out if this value is acceptable; if not, by how much it should be increased.
- `arrayformula(mod({3,5,7} - weekday(A2) - 1, 7))` find the day intervals between *tomorrow* and the acceptable days of week. The `mod` function is needed to wrap things up correctly: e.g., `mod(3 - 6, 7) = mod(-3, 7) = 4`
- Finally, `min` determines the smallest of those day intervals, and adds it to the value of *tomorrow*.

Comment: Glad it worked. There is a checkmark to the left of the post that can be used to indicate this fact.